# Negative and Positive voltage with two different Switching IC

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics

I'm not sure to ASK this question or not it's like a joke but I wanna know how can I make a +/- voltage with just one power source?

maybe should I use two same type switching converter IC and make two different voltage for positive and negative so I know in positive voltage it's possible for example I use the MAX17291
in below picture...

I will read the positive switching source instead of V1 and put the negative switching source instead of V2. Is this possible? Suppose that these two switching devices get their input voltage from the power supply or, for example, the adapter.

[image]

and if these are not an imagine is there any Boost converter with 1 Ampere.

Comment: There’s not enough detail in your drawing to give a concrete answer. Reading between the lines, no, your technique will not work. There are a number of common techniques used to generate a negative voltage rail. There are power supply modules that generate both positive and negative voltage outputs, use a boost converter with a transformer, boost converter configured for negative voltage, charge pump, ringing choke converter….depends on what current, voltage etc you require.

Comment: You can get switching ICs that do things like 5v to +/-12v if that is what you're looking for. Alternatively, if you have a positive rail and want a matches negative rail, capacitive inverters are an IC and a couple small capacitors and will spit out the negative of the input voltage in a few square millimeters of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is no joke. You are user number 257, to have asked this very question, so you have company.

What you ask for is very possible, but the negative side of the supply may not be obtainable using only the MAX17291.

Consider two DC to DC converters, each able to produce a *potential difference* at their outputs of 12V, from whatever source voltage you have. That's easy to build using goodness knows how many ICs, from however many manufacturers exist, designed for that very purpose. What you must consider, though, is the relationship between their output, and the relative potentials at their input.

Take, for example, this circuit from page 19 of the [MAX17291 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max17291.pdf):

[image]

Notice how the input, labelled "INPUT 1.8V TO 5.5V" is with respect to the GND pin on the IC. That is, GND is assumed to be what we call "zero volts", but both input *and* output share this "ground" point. We may redraw that entire circuit as a single modular "black box", the contents of which are unknown, but whose behavior is understood to convert a 5V *potential difference* into a 12V *potential difference*:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCOHlT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The important thing about that diagram is that both input and output share a common ground. What we call "zero volts" at the input is the same potential as "zero volts" at the output.

What you propose would involve two such systems, connected as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA97c9.png)</sup>

So far so good, but there remains the final act of connecting them together, so that node A is 12V *above* ground (\$V_A=0V+12V=+12V\$), and B is 12V *below* ground (\$V_B=0V-12V=-12V\$). With two 12V batteries, this is trivially simple; we simply connect the negative terminal of one battery to the positive terminal of the other, and call that junction "zero volts" or "ground":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7FIyI.png)</sup>

Let's do the same with our two DC-DC converter voltage sources, join the negative side of one to the positive side of the other, this link being show in red here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAn1yS.png)</sup>

Now look carefully. Can you see how the red link causes the output of the lower DC-DC converter to be short-circuited?

This is a huge problem. The only reason we could successfully use this technique with batteries is because those batteries did not share a common ground. They were completely isolated from each other.

Here, though, since both DC-DC converter modules share a common ground, you  *cannot* place their outputs in series without short-circuiting the output of one of the two modules.

To solve this problem, you have two approaches:

1. Use converters that share a common ground, but one of them produces a *negative* output with respect to that common ground point. Such a device would be called a "negative DC-DC converter", or perhaps an "inverting DC-DC converter".
2. Use two positive DC-DC converters, and connect them as we did the batteries, but ensure that the output of one (or both) of the modules be completely isolated from its input, a so-called "isolated DC to DC converter".

Comment: Thank you for your time, I understood your complete explanation.